# How to iteratively call a variable which was defined iteratively in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have iteratively define a variable containing x-coordinates as follows

```
import numpy as np
xCoords = {"%s" % i: np.array([math.cos(2*math.pi*i/360),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], dtype = int) for i in range(0, 360)}
```

However, the `i` in `math.cos(2*math.pi*i/360)` does not iterate over the range. If I print `xCoords["i"][0]` over the range `(0,360)`, I get 0 for each `i > 1`. How do I get the `i` to change within the expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `i` is actually iterating over the values as expected. The problem here is that you take as `dtype` `int`, which causes all values to be casted to an integer. If the value is between 0 and 1 this will result in 0.

If you use for instance `float` you will not have this issue:

```
xCoords = {str(i): np.array([math.cos(2*math.pi*i/360),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], dtype = float) for i in range(0, 360)}
```

I also replaced `"%s" % i` with `str(i)` as it's easier to read. Example output:

```
>>> xCoords["1"][0]
0.9998476951563913
```